# Should Rake be in the same bin directory as ruby and irb and gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, and I'm setting up Ruby on Rails on my Macbook Pro running Snow Leopard. Everything seems to be going smoothly, but I noticed the following issue.

When I run the `which` command in the terminal, "Rake" is showing up in a different directory than "ruby", "gem", and "irb". There is also a "rake" executable in the same directory as "ruby", "gem", and "irb", but again, the "which" command returns the "rake" executable below. Should it return the same path as the others? I wonder if this is a problem, and if so, how should I handle it?

My terminal command:

```
vins-MacBook-Pro:~ $ which ruby gem irb rake
```

My results:

```
/Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
/Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem
/Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine. You're using RVM but the looks of your path. Rake is installed as a gem in the global gemset for 1.9.3-p194. It's pulling the rake executable from the gem's bin directory.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I wasn't sure because the book I used as a reference was a little vague.